# When I run "php artisan migrate" code in terminal I can't create table on http: // localhost / phpmyadmin /

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = TestLaravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

```
at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
   667▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 671▕             throw new QueryException(
    672▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673▕             );
    674▕         }
    675▕ 

      +36 vendor frames 
  37  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Comment: What is your database driver?  Can you give more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- using flags on command you use `php artisan migrate --env=production` may solve problem in some cases
- check file `app/config/database.php` for relevant *host* key to be `'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')`, not *localhost*
- check file `.env` for relevant line to be `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`, not *localhost*